# How to modify 6 byte memory address from je to jne

Tags: assembly, hex

im playing with assembly language and gdb trying to modify a memory address:

+67  00058093  0f84e8000000            je          0x00058181

id like to change the second byte that reads 84 to 85 so that the instruction becomes jne. Then i do the following in gdb after breaking on code:

```
set {char}0x00058094=85
```

but i get the following "andnps %xmm0,%xmm5" instead of jne:

```
(gdb)disas
0x00058093 <-[SWBConditionalImplementations checkRegistration:preferences:callbacks:]+67>:  andnps %xmm0,%xmm5
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: does this disassembly show it only changing a single byte?

Comment: yes, i just need to change 1 byte, the second one thats why i set the value on 0x00058094 instead of 0x00058093 but i get that weird value.. any suggestion ?

Comment: what I meant was, after you issue the command, does the hex output display `0f85e8000000`?

Comment: What is the value @ 00058093 after your change? Also is your machine little endian or big endian?

Comment: Also I am suspicious as to why the instruction is not aligned. xx93?!

Comment: @Necrolis after using set {char} command i call disas to check the changes and i get that line above: 0x00058093 <-[SWBConditionalImplementations ..

Comment: @PavanManjunath , the machine is little endian. The value is what you see below the disas command. Thanks everybody for your help.

Comment: try using `set *((char*)0x00058094) = 0x85` see if that helps

Comment: Yep! that made it, thanks for the quick reply and solution mate!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you are passing a decimal value, not a hex one, you should use `set {char}0x00058094=0x85` or `set {char}0x00058094=133` to do what you wanted, alternatively `set *((char*)0x00058094) = 0x85` would also work.

disassembly makes this a little clearer:

```
0F55E8                             ANDNPS XMM5,XMM0
```

vs.

```
0F85 E8000000                      JNZ 004010F1
```

85 is 0x55, which is why you get the SIMD instruction and no the JNE you wanted.

*(I'm a bit disappointed that I didn't notice that sooner...)*

Comment: he says his machine is little endian. So we need to write @ `0x00058093+5` right?

Comment: @PavanManjunath: not in this case, because we are writing a **byte**, we can use the exact address of that byte, which is `0x00058094` in this case